# Index out of range while web scrapping yahoo finance news

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, continue, index-error

here is the code, after importing libraries and defining values :

```
y = 0 
while y < 20:
    headline =(soup3.find_all('div',{'class': 'Ov(h) Pend(44px) Pstart(25px)'})[y].find_all('a')[-1].text)
    print(str(y+1)+ ")" + headline)
    print(soup3.find_all('div',{'class': 'Ov(h) Pend(44px) Pstart(25px)'})[y].find_all('p')[-1].text)
    print()
    y+=1
```

Here is the error message:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-9b071c6ecb87> in <module>
      1 y = 0
      2 while y < 20:
----> 3     headline =(soup3.find_all('div',{'class': 'Ov(h) Pend(44px) Pstart(25px)'})[y].find_all('a')[-1].text)
      4     print(str(y+1)+ ")" + headline)
      5     print(soup3.find_all('div',{'class': 'Ov(h) Pend(44px) Pstart(25px)'})[y].find_all('p')[-1].text)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I get 8 news articles before this message, but I know for a fact yahoo finance news contains a lot more than just 8 articles : they alternate between two different 'class' references, i.e 'Ov(h) Pend(44px) Pstart(25px)' and 'Ov(h) Pend(14%) Pend(44px)--sm1024'... my guess is instead of continuing when it encounters the other type it gives the error message...

How can I solve this issue to get a return for all of one type of news, or both in the same line if possible ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the URL and what information do you want to get from the page?

Comment: Url is the yahoo finance news section and i’m trying to get title and description… I’ve identified the correct references (there are two types of articles) but they are spaced appart and alternate. So, I get the first few articles but then receive the index out of range error